# ionic contenteditable can’t scroll in ios/android and difficult to get focus

Tags: javascript, html, ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I normally need to click twice to focus on the contenteditable div , and if my input was long enough ,there is no scroll bar showed up (it's normal in safari). If wraped this div with ion-scroll, then it can't get focus at all. That's my div:

```
<div contenteditable="true" data-tap-disabled="true" overflow-scroll="true" style="height:200px;overflow:scroll;background-color:red"></div>
```

Comment: It seem issues from browser in mobile. I was try contenteditable to edit mail content in my app but it not successful and waiting solution :D

Comment: And one of the owners of ionic project tell me contenteditable is not recommend . I am sort of desperate .